# NHibernate - setting long string as a parameter for query

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, nhibernate

I'm constructing a query like this:

```
private void Test()
{ 
    ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    var query = session.GetNamedQuery("testQuery");
    string s = BuildVeryLongString(); // length more that 4000 chracters
    query.SetParameter("Param", s, NHibernateUtil.String);
    query
        .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(type))
        .List<Type>();
}
```

In the DB-profiler I can see that the type of `Param` is `nvarchar(4000)` that is not enough. Is there a way to say NHibernate that I'm going to use longer strings?
P.S. DB is MSSQL 2005.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Param` is used as a constraint against a mapped property, the query will try to use the correct data type and length for the parameter, according to the mapped property. Does `Param` correlate to a property mapped to an nvarchar(max) column? If so, have you set the data length correctly? You should set the datalength on a string column to a length over 4000 (4001 should work), if you want Nhibernate to recognize it as nvarchar(max).

Comment: NHibernate things StringClob == SQL Server's `text` as the data type. I'm sure in most cases that will work fine for you, and obviously if your column's data type is actually `text`, then that's perfect. However, if you're using nvarchar(max) or varchar(max), you should consider removing "StringClob" and setting the length in the mapping as I mentioned. That way you know everything is mapped exactly right, and you can use Schema Exporter (assuming you even care about it).