# NHibernate stored procedures - set parameter sizes?

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, stored-procedures

I'm executing a stored procedure using `GetNamedQuery` and setting a string parameter using `SetString`. NHibernate sets the string parameter to be an `NVarchar(4000)`. My string parameter value is actually longer than this and so gets truncated.

Is there any way to tell NHibernate to use a longer string type when executing the query? The query is defined in the mapping file as simply. `exec dbo.ProcessUploads :courseId, :uploadxml`

Edit: neither of my parameters are properties of the enties involved.

Comment: Check this other question to see if helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626394/how-does-one-make-nhibernate-stop-using-nvarchar4000-for-insert-parameter-stri

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since NHibernate doesn't have enough information to set the parameter length automatically, you have to do it manually.

Example:

```
session.GetNamedQuery("ProcessUploads")
       .SetParameter("courseId", courseId)
       .SetParameter("uploadXml", uploadXml, NHibernateUtil.StringClob)
       .ExecuteUpdate();
```

In this case I'm using `StringClob`, which would translate to `NVARCHAR(max)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should show us or check your HBM file for parameters. There you can specify field/property type, lenght...

Here you can read about in official [nHibernate documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-property)

Comment: Just to add to this answer... NHibernate is using mapped property to figure out the length of parameter. More info on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932841/nhibernate-setting-long-string-as-a-parameter-for-query

Comment: The parameters I'm setting aren't properties of the entity involved. The problematic one is an xml string which is processed by the stored proc.